# Disabling a button with jquery stop sending input to server in chrome--MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, button

My issue seems to be classic but I can't find a solution.  I'm using **MVC3**.  I have form that accepts inputs from the user and submits.  I want to disable the submit button when the user clicks on it and enable it again when the user starts entering new inputs.  Basically, I don't want the user to click the button and submit the same inputs multiple times.  I use **jquery** to disable and enable the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#GenerateDrawings').click(function () {
            $('#GenerateDrawings').attr('disabled', true);
        });

        $('#txtOrderNumber').click(function () {
            $('#GenerateDrawings').attr('disabled', false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The GUI works fine for all browsers I tested, but it does not submit inputs back to the server in **chrome** and **IE 9.0 or older**.  It does submit input in **IE 10.0 or later**.  I tried to put the **jquery** script at top and bottom of the page.  It does not make any difference.

I don't know what I did wrong.  I've spent hours on this.

Here's my view code:

```
@model TeklaWebClientMVC.Models.MSDModel


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#GenerateDrawings').click(function () {
            $('#GenerateDrawings').attr('disabled', true);
        });

        $('#txtOrderNumber').click(function () {
            $('#GenerateDrawings').attr('disabled', false);
        });
    });
</script>
<br />

<h2><i class="icon-cog"></i>Generate Drawings</h2>

<div class="span5 pull-left"  >
    <div>
        <img src="../../img/perspective.png" alt="perspective" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span6 pull-right " id ="MSDInput">


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label class="span4"  >*Order Number:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Request.OrderNumber, new { @class = "span8", id ="txtOrderNumber" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Request.OrderNumber)

    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label class="span4"  >*Parts to Create:</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Request.PartsToCreate, Model.GetPartsToCreate(), new { @class = "span8" })
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label class="span4"  >*Drawing Template:</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Request.DrawingTemplate, Model.GetDrawingTemplates(), new { @class = "span8" })
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label class="span4"  >*Company:</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Request.Company, Model.GetCompanies(), new { @class = "span8" })
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label class="span4"  >*Output Format:</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Request.OutputFormat, Model.GetOutputFormats(), new { @class = "span8" })
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label class="span4"  >*Email Notification:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Request.Email, new { @class = "span8" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Request.Email)

    </div>
    <div >
        <b>@ViewBag.Message</b>
    </div>
    <div>
    <br />
    <button id="GenerateDrawings"   type="submit" value="Generate Drawings" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Generate Drawings</button>
@*    <input type="button"  id="GenerateDrawings" value="Generate Drawings" class="btn btn-block btn-success" />*@
    </div>
    <div>
        <label  ><i>* is required field</i></label>
    </div>

}
</div>
@*<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#GenerateDrawings:submit').click(function () {
        $('#GenerateDrawings:submit').attr('disabled', true);
    });

    $('#txtOrderNumber').click(function () {
        $('#GenerateDrawings:submit').attr('disabled', false);
    });

</script>*@
```

Comment: lol, this is easy. First of all, take control of your form submit. Look up jQuery's Ajax api. Second, use it like so `var ajaxSubmit; $('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault; if (ajaxSubmit) ajaxSubmit.abort(); ajaxSubmit = $.ajax({ ..options.. }); })` That eliminates alot of headache alone. As you can see, I make a global variable to asign the ajax call to, then check if it exist (would happen on dblclick), if it does, then it aborts the previous call and starts over! Use the `beforeSend` to disable the button, then use the `complete` or `success` call back to renable button.

Comment: but doing this, I have to use ajax call.  I still want to use my MVC form submit.  Is there a way to do it without making an ajax call?  Thanks

Comment: if I make an ajax call, does MVC validation stuff still work?  I have a lot of validation code behind the sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As with my comment, further example of how to tackle these issues with jQuery and Ajax:

```
$(function() {
    var ajaxSubmit;
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (ajaxSubmit) ajaxSubmit.abort();
        ajaxSubmit = $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { 
                $('#GenerateDrawings').prop('disabled', true);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //  might send back "success" or "fail" or something like that
                if (data.toLowerCase() == 'success') {
                    $('#GenerateDrawings').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        })
    })
})
```

## jQuery Ajax